# Parsing specific data from the result obtained from RESTClient

Tags: java, selenium

I am testing the registration flow through selenium IDE. I am using the REST Client to get the data and extract specific information (in my Code ID) from the result obtained. I am getting Index Out of bound Exception while I am deleting(for the delete method) a chunk of code and reiterating it until i get the ID. My code is mentioned below:

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(value)
for(int x=0; x<value.length()-9;){
   int m = s.indexOf(value, x);
   int n = s.indexOf("},");
   s.delete(m, n);
   x += n+1;
}
```

I have to delete the chunk of braces until I find the specific ID among the other ID's present .

Thanks,
Java Beginner

Comment: I don't understand what it is you are trying to extract nor where the IOOBE is coming from. It might be helpful to 1)give an example of <code>value</code>, 2) give an example of what it is you are trying to extract, & 3) provide a stacktrace showing the exception. Also, what is the significance of subtracting 9 from value's length?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the value does not contain any character of `"},"` in `s.indexOf("},")`, because of this the return value for `int n = s.indexOf("},");` is `-1`, then when you call `s.delete(m, n);` the value of `n` less than `m`, after that the method `throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException()` exception, So you need to validate the string `value` if contain `"},"` or you can skip the deleting if the `(n != -1 && m != -1)`

The Code:

```
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(value);
    for (int x = 0; x < value.length() - 9;) {
        int m = s.indexOf(value, x);
        int n = s.indexOf("},");
        if (n != -1 && m != -1) {
            s.delete(m, n);
        }
        x += n + 1;
    }
```

I don't know what is the logic for `value.length() - 9` and `x += n + 1`, By the way if you need to parse Restful WebService use some API (e.g. XML DOM libraries, XPP, JSON) is better and easier, The parse are depends on what the response type XML or JSON.